# File Permissions error in Java Applet

Tags: java, file, permissions, japplet

I have a Java applet that requires the use of some folders to read in some files and such. The folders are in the proper location and are sitting in the same directory as the index.html (which runs the applet). Here is the error that JApplet spits out:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.util.DeployAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(DeployAWTUtil.java:116)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.runOnEDT(Plugin2Manager.java:3541)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3072)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission ./results read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
    at java.io.File.list(File.java:971)
    at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1129)
    at WhoHasMore.JShellFrame.getDefaultResultsFileName(JShellFrame.java:453)
    at WhoHasMore.JShellFrame.<init>(JShellFrame.java:28)
    at WhoHasMore.<init>(WhoHasMore.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$13.run(Plugin2Manager.java:3060)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:647)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

As you can see, the error seems to be coming from

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission ./results read)
```

Why is the access denied to read from the folder called "results"? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're trying to use (`java.io.File.listFiles`) does not work over HTTP. You will need to choose another way of listing files, such as putting a list of files in a text file at a known URL and downloading that, or making it part of the applet jarfile.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the access denied to read from the folder called "results"?

The Java sandbox is preventing the applet from accessing the file system on the user's machine.

> How do I fix this?

If you want your applet to be able to do this kind of thing, you must:

- create a signed JAR, and
- get the user to accept the certificate / your JAR file as a trusted application.

Comment: Can I do it using a policy file? If so, how do I do that and what should the file name be? Where would the policy file be located?

Comment: *"The folders are in the proper location and are sitting in the same directory as the index.html (which runs the applet)."*  This is ***not*** the client file-system, but the server.  @duskwuff pegged the right approach.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - agreed.  I was too focussed on the problem of making the exception go away rather than the bigger one of making the overall application do what the OP really wants it to do.

Comment: No @duskwuff was incorrect. I was able to sign the jar, wrap the listFiles() call in an AcccessControll.doPrivileged(), and it worked fine. It has nothing to do with HTTP and everything to do with permissions.